# cocoa - quickly release all IBOUtlets

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a view with many retained IBOutlets, loaded from a XIB.

I have read that they have to be released when the controller's dealloc method is called.

May I use a cycle to do this(also to avoid releasing each outlet separately)?

something like

```
for(UIView *v in self.view.subviews){
[v release];
v=nil;
}
```

?

also, after that, should I release the view as well?

Comment: Have you tried the code you posted, did it work? I'd recommend against anything ambiguous like that, just explicitly release what you have to release there can't be _that_ many.

Comment: I tried it, I got the following error  *** -[CALayer release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4c65f10   My concern is find a method I can use in every viewController.

Comment: You've just answered your question.

Comment: You have that error because you over-released memory.

Comment: sure my method isn't working. but maybe there was a way to access IBoutlets from the code I was not aware of. that method was just to give the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would only make sense if you've actually retained every single subview, and even then it seems like asking for trouble -- if you ever wanted to change your .xib, you'd have to remember to update you code as well. And there may also be non-view objects in a nib that can be connected to outlets, like view controllers.

There are only so many views you can fit on an iPhone- or iPad-sized screen, so it's hard to imagine that you have more than a few dozen outlets. I think the prudent thing to do here is to simply release each one separately. This is what and iOS developer would expect to see, and it won't be any slower than using a loop. It'll be more code, yes, but the code will be easy to understand.

Comment: There's no indication at run time that a given instance variable is an outlet. Furthermore, there's no requirement that an outlet retain its requirements. So there's really no practical way for your code to inspect itself and decide what should and shouldn't be released.

Answer (score 0):

`self.view` is automatically released on `UIViewController` deallocation, and subviews also, if not retained by your code.

You should re-read the chapter on memory management in Apple Documentation... ;)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote like a `releaseVars` function, which takes address of variables, release them and set to `nil`. This save some lines of code, but still you have to manually take care of them.